# tab key is not working as expected when using jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had some weird result from jquery events, though I am not fully convinced whether it is a jquery issue. I hope some jquery geeks can answer this.

I had the following code snippet in my html page, to change the focus to the `second` input box once user enter a string of length 9 in `first` input box. This auto-focusing is working smoothly. But when I press tab from `first` input box, it is always skipping the `second` input box and goes to the next html element to `second` input box.

```
$("input.first").change(function (e){
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.length == 9){
        $("input[id='second']").focus();
    }
});
```

I tried putting `tabindex` property to html elements still it continued its misbehavior. But at the end when I changed `change` event to `keypress` event tab key started to flow as expected.

Is there anyone who could explain why this happens? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: As a sidenote `$("input[id='second']")` is very bad `$("#second")` will do

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qmWBR/1/

Comment: If this behavior differs depending on first.length>8, I would say, as a complete random guess, that is because the change is processed before the tab. So your second gets focus, then the tab is processed => next element.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: thanks for the notes. I shall take care of it in future. :)

Comment: @jbl: your comment seems to be valid. But even if I dont change the value in the first box and press tab, the problem exits.

Comment: you should post a jsfiddle, or at least a page that illustrates your problem, as well as the browser it occurs on. BTW, where does "text" come from ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Actually, `#second` will target ALL elements with ID of second. He might just want inputs so his code is fine. I personally try to make it as specific as possible to avoid issues with other code added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can add tab index to controls manually. I hope it will work.

```
$(function() {
  var tabindex = 1;
  $('input').each(function() {
     if (this.type != "hidden") {
       var $input = $(this);
       $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
       tabindex++;
     }
  });
});
```